# laravel storage method not displaying images on another OS or machine

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I store images using this method:

```
'avatar' => $r->avatar->store('public/avatars')
```

and get them like

```
<img src="{{Storage::url($user->avatar)}}" style="border-radius:50%;height:30px;width:30px;"  style alt="">
```

They get displayed on the local machine, but not in others. What could be the issue?

Comment: When you view the page locally and use the browser developer tools to inspect the code for the `img` tag what is the `src` set to?

Comment: it points to /storage/avatars/XcsXDZOgB406aViR0Bpg2Paz2dWsWQ0lIVPJMknm.jpeg

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of user's avatar column, you might have some sort symlinks enabled on local machine, Instead you can also use `public_path`, as storage should not be exposed outside.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-public-path

Also check file visibility

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#storing-files

Answer (score 0):

you have stored file inside `public/avatars`
be sure `$user->avatar` has `public/avatars` concatenated if not you might have to

```
{{Storage::url("public/avatars/".$user->avatar)}}
```

use this as source of your image

Answer (score 0):

had to delete the public/storage folder on the other machine then run

```
php artisan storage:link
```

images started showing as normal